# How to customize an extension in medium editor?

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I'd like to change the "anchor" extension button label to use the Unicode symbol for browser link - (U+1F517). I don't want to install fontawesome.

To do this I need some way to either modify the extension or subclass it. Any suggestions?

Comment: So it turns out that the correct answer here, for me anyway. is 'use draft.js'. Since I'm working in React, I gradually discovered that medium-editor and react don't really play too well together (you can kind of get them to work but it's flaky.) I switched over to draft.js and I'm pretty happy.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone was looking for a simple way to override the the content of any of the built-in MediumEditor buttons, you can specify some extra properties during the initialization of the MediumEditor object.  For the button text, you'd want to override the `defaultContent` property of the button, which accepts a block of html:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', {
    toolbar: {
        buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline',
            {
                name: 'anchor',
                defaultContent: '<i>My Unicode Char</i>'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

You can find more examples of the simple button properties that can be overriden in this fashion in the [Button Options Section](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor#button-options) of the MediumEditor README.  This includes the ability to add custom classes or additional attributes to the button element.